# Dismiss UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UITableViewRowAction set up and working. The only thing I can't work out is how to dismiss the UITableViewRowAction once an action has been selected. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious. Here is my current setup:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "In", handler:{action, indexpath in
        //Some code to execute here
    });
    moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)

    return [moreRowAction];
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You dismiss the action in the handler which gets called when the action is tapped. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowaction/1614893-init) describes the handler as follows

> The block to execute when the user taps the button associated with this action. UIKit makes a copy of the block you provide. When the user selects the action represented by this object, UIKit executes your handler block on the app’s main thread.

Independently, I suppose you could just set the table views `editing` property to false.

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: @Mundi What about showing the action of a row in the TableView in code?

Comment: Assuming you are going to do self.tableView.editing=false, I am wondering if you need [unowned self] here to avoid a circular reference and possible memory leak.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

tableView.editing = NO;

Answer (score 1):

Calling `tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` seems to work only some of the time. Eventually the table view seems to get into a state where it no longer displays the edit actions.

I have found that simply calling `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` works more reliably.

Comment: Note that this does not appear to work if the cell does not have a reuse identifier. This may be because `UITableView` requires two cells to perform the transition from one state to the other (even though the animation is set to `.none`).

Answer (score 1):

It works for mi in Swift 3:

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```