# display rowActions in NSTableView OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, swipe, nstableview

I want to create a swipable tableview same as it is present in the IOS. But I am not able to find any document related to that. Also I was going through the NSTableView Documentation and fund the following.

```
/* View Based TableView: rowActionsVisible can be queried to determine if the "row actions" (see: tableView:rowActionsForRow:edge:) are visible or not. Set rowActionsVisible=NO to hide the row actions. Setting rowActionsVisible=YES is currently not supported and will throw an exception. This property is not encoded in the nib.
 */
@property BOOL rowActionsVisible NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
```

At the end of the Comment it says `Setting rowActionsVisible=YES is currently not supported and will throw an exception.` So, how are we going to set the action?
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the new Swipeable table functionality was added in MacOS 10.11, and it looks like the way to do it is via implementing the NSTableViewDelegate method:

[`optional func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge edge: NSTableRowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:rowActionsForRow:edge:)

Where you can set up [NSTableViewRowAction objects via a relatively straightforward init method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTableViewRowAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTableViewRowAction).

Comment: in my case the delegate is not called.

Comment: make sure you are setting your table's delegate via Interface Builder or even programatically.

Comment: I have added the delegate. My other delegates are getting called. but not this one. My Mac version:10.10.5.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning MacOS 10.10... this new delegate method comes in with MacOS 10.11, which means MacOS 10.10 & older does not have this ability.  To really test this out, you need to work with El Capitan.

Comment: Do you know how to dismiss the action? Like in this question for iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197826/dismiss-uitableviewrowaction ?

Comment: @Klaas `[tableView setRowActionsVisible:NO]` will do it.